# How to serialize xml date value to DateTime class in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am passing the following xml

```
<PolicyNumber>6456365A1</PolicyNumber>
<EffectiveDate>2015-10-01T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
<ExpirationDate>2016-10-01T00:00:00</ExpirationDate>
```

to class through fiddler post.But the Values in the following class

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Parameter
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember] 
        public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    }
```

The value for policy number getting passed as expected.The value for DateTime is not getting passed instead it has its default value. I am posting it using fiddler to web api mvc.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the Deserialization code ? And also why didn't you put `DataMember` attribute on the effective date ? Does `ExpirationDate` works ?

Comment: You don't have a valid xml file.  XML must have the identification line and have only one root tag.  You need to wrap the xml data you are receiving with the identification line and root tab before de-serializing.

Comment: Expiration Date also not working

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make it a private member that is only used for serialization.

```
[DataContract]
public class AutoIDCardParameter
{
    [DataMember(Name = "PolicyNumber")]
    public string PolicyNumber;

    [DataMember(Name = "EffectiveDate")]
    private string _EffectiveDate {
        get {
            return EffectiveDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
        }
        set {
            DateTime.TryParse(value, out EffectiveDate);
        }
    }

    public DateTime EffectiveDate;

    // ....
}
```

Comment: I forgot about data member names.

Answer (score 1):

The order is wrong here.  `DataContractSerializer` will use alphabetical order unless you specify otherwise (see [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx)), so it's expecting `EffectiveDate`, `ExpirationDate`, and then `PolicyNumber`.

You need to either re-arrange your XML to be in that order, or you need to specify the order on the class via attributes:

```
[DataContract]
public class Parameter
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
}
```